# How do I run find and cp commands concurrently in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, find, xargs

How do I run `find` and `cp` commands concurrently? I have tried this:

```
find -name "*pdf*" | xargs cp $1 ./
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-exec` option:

```
find ./ -name "*pdf*" -exec cp -t . {} \+
```

The `{}` is replaced with the current file names being processed.

From the man page for `find`:

> `-exec command {} +`
>
> ...the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end..
>   The command line is built in much the same way that `xargs` builds its  command lines.

Note the use of `-t` (target directory) option (which is a GNU extension). We cannot use `-exec cp {} . +`, because the matched file names are appended to the end of the command line, while destination would have to be specified last. Another workaround is to invoke `sh`:

```
find ./ -name "*pdf*" -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" .' '' {} +
```

I have habitually escaped the `+` character. Note, you should escape special characters of the `find` syntax to protect them from expansion by the shell. In particular, there is likely no need in backslash before `+`, because most shells will interpret it as a string (it will not be expanded to something different). However, you will definitely have to escape/quote the `;` (which applies the command to each file sequentially):

```
find -name "*pdf*" -exec cp -f {} . ';'
```

Comment: the first one didn't work for me (linux, bash 4.3.46)... error ``find: missing argument to `-exec'`` ... this one does `find -name '*pdf*' -exec cp -t ./ {} \+`

Comment: @Sundeep, fixed