# Using cp -ur, but update only directories

Tags: bash, filesystems, cp

I have two directories that I want to contain mostly the same information. 
I wrote the basic script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Update the two folders
cp -vur ../catkin_ws/src .
cp -vur . ../catkin_ws/src
```

Now I want to change this, to only update the directories and their content but not other files on the top level directory, like the bash script itself.

If that is not possible, is there a way to exclude certain files during the update?

Comment: reading the man page of `cp`, I didn't find any option to exclude specific files. One workaround you could do is to combine `cp` and the `-i` flag (thant prompts wether or not you want to replace a folder) along with an `expect` script. Otherwise, you could first list all the existing files in your folders, store it in a variable, remove the files you want to exclude and then execute your cp command

Comment: You probably want to look at using `rsync` instead. In addition to allowing you to exclude files, it will skip files that are already identical (which is slightly smarter than `cp -u`, which will copy an identical file that it has a newer timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to synchronize `../catkin_ws/src` with the current directory, and the current script is located in the current directory. As far as I understand, you want to synchronize only the top-level directories including their contents, but not other types of nodes possibly located at the top level, i.e. directly within `../catkin_ws/src`, or `./`.

Then it is easily done with `find` command:

```
src_dir="../catkin_ws/src"

find "$src_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -exec cp -vru {} . \;

find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -exec cp -vru {} "$src_dir" \;
```

where `{}` stands for the next directory found.

If you want to filter further, you may use extra options such as `-name`, `-path`, or `-regex`. For example, the following skips directory `x`:

```
find "$src_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  ! -name 'x' \
  -exec cp -vru {} . \;
```

where `!` is causes the next expression to return `True`, if the expression is false, i.e. acts as some kind of logical `NOT` operator.

The drawback of the above commands is that the `cp` command is launched for each folder sequentially (due to `\;`). If you want to run single `cp` command for all sources, you may use an approach described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392838/how-do-i-run-find-and-cp-commands-concurrently-in-linux/40392881#40392881) answer.

P.S.

I didn't try to suggest better way to synchronize the directories, but only suggested a way to fix your current approach.